# grep command, find words starting and ending with a letter

Tags: regular-expression

So I understand that if you want to match beginning of a word with a specific letter(s), you would use `\<`, ex, `\<Aa`. Vice versa for end of a word, `\>`. How would you combine these two commands together?

for example, if you do `\<Aag\>` it will just match the word. Is there a way to separate these two commands?

Comment: From the questions, it is unclear what are you trying to accomplish: combine or separate? By the way, `\<` and `\>` are not part of POSIX standard for grep (I'd say they are GNU extensions), so the question should be tagged appropriately.

Comment: I'm trying to find words that begin with ”qu” and end with ”y” But if I do \<quy\> that would just find the word 'quy'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\<` and `\>` operators are some non-standard regex operators found as extensions in some `grep` implementations with or without `-E`.

In most implementations, they match at the boundary between a non-word character (or the start of the subject) and a word character, and between a word character and a non-word character (or the end of the subject) respectively, word characters being alphanumeric characters or underscores.

Some `grep`/regexp implementations have `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` for that instead and some have `\b` (from perl) which matches either type of boundary.

Those that do support any of these generally also support the `-w` option which matches on words.

`\<Aag\>` matches inside `foo-Aag` as the `\<` matches inbetween `-` and `A`, and `\>` matches between `g` and the end of the subject (subject being lines for `grep`).

Some `grep` implementations also support `\w` to match any single word character. So with those, to find any word that starts with `Aa` and ends in `g`, you'd use `\<Aa\w*g\>`. The standard equivalent of `\w` would be `[[:alnum:]_]`, so `\<Aa[[:alnum:]_]*g\>` would be slightly more portable. With some implementations, you may need `\bAa[[:alnum:]_]*g\b` or the equivalent with `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`.

In standard `grep`, you could use:

```
grep -E '(^|[^[:alnum:]_)Aa[[:alnum:]_]*g([^[:alnum:]_]|$)'
```

Or:

```
grep -x '\(.*[^[:alnum:]_]\)\{0,1\}Aa[[:alnum:]_]*g\([^[:alnum:]_].*\)\{0,1\}'
```

with default BREs.

If your `grep` supports `-P` for perl regexps, then

```
grep -P '\bAa\w*g\b'
```

Or:

```
grep -Pw 'Aa\w*g'
```

Would work. Or you could use the real thing:

```
perl -ne 'print if /\bAa\w*g\b/'
```

(though beware that by default `\w` matches only on ASCII letters).